# Could not read config file while deploying static content in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

It shows error in FileResolver file. 
[image]

Comment: please check file permission.

Comment: How to check that? I am new to Magento

Comment: Verify app/etc/config.php

Comment: Set permission with 777

Comment: I am using Magento in windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling it again.